# Failed to load a scene from an sks file

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a sks file containing a scene (GameScene class), and I implemented initWithCoder: in GameScene. I'm trying to load the scene in the controller this way:

```
let file = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("GameScene", ofType: "sks")!
if let scene = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(file) as? GameScene 
{...}
```

But the block is never executed and initWithCoder: is never called.

Comment: Try `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { ... }` instead.

Comment: It's already declared as "required".

Comment: Try using `if let scene = GameScene (fileNamed:"GameScene") { ... }` to load your .sks file

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri What you are currently doing, fails due to fact that instance returned by unarchiveObjectWithFile is SKScene, not GameScene. May I ask what is the point of creating scene like this instead of using convenience fileNamed ?

Comment: @0x141E That might fail if there is no custom implementation provided for all other designated initializers from a superclass (SKScene) because the convenience fileNamed will not be inherited (due to rule 2 about [automatic initializer inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID222)). Still, this is guessing and more code from OP's GameScene is needed for confirmation. But I would say that will happen if he try to use fileNamed right now.

Comment: The problem is that ever since I implemented initWithCoder:, GameScene(fileNamed:) can't be used (Error: "argument labels '(fileNamed:)' do not match any available overloads"). The simple solution would be to delete initWithCoder: and initialize the scene in initWithSize:, but I'm trying to understand the reason of this behavior.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I described that in my last comment. `fileNamed` convenience initializer is not inherited in your case because your code breaking the rule 2 found in that link.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Note that you do not write the `override` modifier when overriding a required designated initializer. You just write `required` keyword, but because that is an actual override, all the rules about automatic initializer inheritance still apply.

Comment: @Whirlwind other than init:size (the designated initializer) and init:coder (required initializer), what do you need to include in GameScene to satisfy Rule 2?

Comment: @0x141E You have to override init() as well ...