# How to change the default SKScene that displays on startup

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've been developing a game that has been done in the single default GameScene created by XCode. Now I want to add more screens including a title screen that displays before the GameScene does and a 'Game Over' scene. The game over scene is transitioned from the GameScene and back and works fine but I cant get the title screen to display despite altering the code in GameViewController.swift:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    //Original default code:
    //if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
    //modified code
        if let scene = Titles(fileNamed:"Titles") {
            //<...more code...>
        }
```

The app still runs but just displays a blank screen. I note that the GameScene file also has a GameScene.sks which I think is a graphical representation of the scene content. Do I need to create another .sks or link this to the new default scene even though the scene content is being added programmatically.

I could simply move all the code from GameScene to a new SKScene and use GameScene as the titles but I was curious about the problem and how to resolve it. Any ideas?

Many Thanks,
Kw

Answer (score 2):

Yes - initialising a scene with '`fileNamed`' refers to a .sks file, so you should create one.

In this line of code:

```
let scene = Titles(fileNamed:"Titles")
```

you are create a new scene object called `scene` of type `Titles`. This should match the class name in your swift file i.e. in `titles.swift` you should have:

```
class Titles: SKScene {
```

The `fileNamed`: is just one of many initialisers for `SKSCene` and this specifies a .sks file to load. If you want to place all content in your scene programmatically, perhaps use:

```
let scene = Titles(size: CGSize(width: 1536, height: 2048))
```

This question and it's accepted answer might help with any potential problems you might encounter - [How to add an .sks files to existing Swift/Sprite-Kit project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39807702/1430420)