# Gamescene.swift and Gamescene.sks not working together

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am having a problem with my xCode project. I have a whole gamescene.swift file worth of code (600 lines). But the code will not run. When i run my game in simulator the simulator shows the standard gamescene.sks color, alongside with my ads, but it is not showing any of my code. I have already checked that the custom class in gamescene.sks is correct. Everything is working, expect for the gamescene.swift code, it will not run.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class GameViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var GoogleBannerView: GADBannerView!
@IBOutlet weak var MainMenu: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    GoogleBannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-13***46014918193/236762****"
    GoogleBannerView.rootViewController = self
    GoogleBannerView.load(GADRequest())


    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = false
        view.showsNodeCount = false
        view.showsPhysics = true
    }



}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        return .allButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .all
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

}

Comment: I think you need to post both your GameViewController.swift code and your GameScene,swift code. (the latter in a reduced form, if it is 600 lines).

Comment: The problem is not that the code is not working, it is that the code will not run

Comment: it seems like there is a problem with the synergy between the gamescene.swift and the gamescene.sks

Comment: There is no errors when i run my app, but the sks is simply showing without inputting the code from gamescene.swift

Comment: If you put some print statement in didMoveToView, do you see them? Are you sure that your .swift file is actually getting called? Is the right .sks file being displayed? If you put something in the .sks file, do you see it in the simulator?

Comment: The project did work. But i somehow managed to mess up my project in my plist file. After that the project was corrupted. i transfered all my files to the new project and now i cant seem to make the gamescene.swift file run. If i place anything in the sks file it appears. but the print statement did not run.

Comment: I think the problem is that the gamescene.swift file is not getting called. but i dont know why

Comment: Can you add your gameViewController.swift file to your question please.. Is the information here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42113413/1430420 of any use?

Comment: updated the question with the gameviewcontroller file

Comment: the other question was not of any use, unfortunately

Comment: Are you sure that the custom class referred in your `GameScene.sks` is GameScene? Edit .sks and have a look in the "Custom Class Inspector". Looks like you created the .sks by yourself.

Comment: What happens if you put print("Loading gamescene now...")  before the presentScene? Do you get the message?

Comment: In your GameScene.swift file, do you have class GameScene: SKScene {  ?

Comment: class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, GADBannerViewDelegate {

Comment: The print("Loading gamescene now...") is not showing. It looks like there is no connection between the GameViewController, Gamescene.swift and gamescene.sks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

i managed to fix the problem after countless hours of trying.

```
    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
```

this is the working code. the problem was that instead of specifying what scene i was suppose to lead i had written

```
if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
```

the simple fix was changing the "SKScene" to my SKScene name.

```
if let scene = GameScene(Filenamed: "GameScene")
```

Hope this helps the countless other out there that are having trouble with this problem!

Answer (score 6):

I've had similar problems to this on SOME of my projects but not all. Even on projects that were working and I duplicated the code and scene files for another project they would stop working. I discovered that if there are any spaces or special characters in the your project name the scene files and items in the sks files will not load unless you put in the "Module" name below the Custom Class type.

For me my project was named "Crag & Pig" before any of the sks file would register I had to enter "Crag_Pig" in the "Module" for all of the items in the sks file.

Interestingly, on any projects that didn't have spaces or special characters I didn't have to enter any thing for Module

Comment: Interesting input, however my sks are named GameScene, so there is not space between my file names

Comment: It's not the Scene. It's the Project that you need to look at. what I was referring to is if your project name has any space or special characters in it

Comment: I am just beginning in xcode game development and had this same issue where my Project Name had a space in it. If you look in the "Bundle Identifier" field in the General project settings you should be able to see something like [Project-Name]. Notice the hyphen as it was in my case. Modify the .sks Custom Class Module field to the [Project-Name] hyphenated value. Solved an issue I was having with scene transitions.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks. Even the default template in Xcode for SpriteKit Games has this very issue. That since the release of swift 4 + iOS 11. 
I always thought it was me somehow, but never took the time to find why. Until now out of curiosity. I changed the line you wrote/fixed and voila.

Just changed the capitals in the parameter fileNamed: of your line

```
if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
```

Comment: This is still the case for Xcode 11 in late 2019... The above solution(s) still works though.